# Can not see the the marker of my current location on the MapView

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to add a marker of my current location on a MapView, but the marker is not shown, the code is like:

```
mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this.getContext());
........
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    MapsInitializer.initialize(getContext());
    googleMapObj = googleMap;
    googleMapObj.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    getMyLastLocation();
    moveCamera.....
    googleMapObj.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
}

private void getMyLastLocation(){
    mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                Location location = task.getResult();
                geopoint = new GeoPoint(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
                Log.d(TAG, geopoint.toString());
                googleMapObj.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(geopoint.getLongitude(),geopoint.getLongitude()))
                        .title("My Location"));

            }
        }
    });
}
```

I am wondering why the Marker is not shown on the MapView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your function :

```
   Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
   LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            markerOptions.position(latLng);
            markerOptions.title("Current Position");

           markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.
              defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
            mCurrLocationMarker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
            mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLngo, 11));
```